# The requested resource is not available. 404

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I think that a mistake somewhere in the servlet.
Which leads to a 404 error when linking from index to users.
Please, tell me if you notice it.

Project structure -

[image: Project structure]

web.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
<display-name>SQL Manager</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.dubinets.app"/>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<!-- Database Information -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.dubinets.app.model.User</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--UserDao and UserService beans-->
<bean id="userDao" class="com.dubinets.app.dao.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userService" class="com.dubinets.app.service.UserServiceImpl">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.dubinets.app"/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

index.jsp -

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SQl Manager</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="<c:url value="/users"/>" target="_blank">Users list</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

users.jsp -

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="from" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Users Page</title>

</head>
<body>
<a href="../../index.jsp">Back to main menu</a>
<br/>
<br/>

<h1>User List</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

UserController.java -

```
import com.dubinets.app.model.User;
import com.dubinets.app.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

public class UserController {
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "userService")
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", new User());
        model.addAttribute("listUsers", this.userService.listUsers());

        return "users";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
        if(user.getId() == 0){
            this.userService.addUser(user);
        }else {
            this.userService.updateUser(user);
        }

        return "redirect:/users";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
    public String removeUser(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        this.userService.removeUser(id);

        return "redirect:/users";
    }

    @RequestMapping("edit/{id}")
    public String editUser(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", this.userService.getUserById(id));
        model.addAttribute("listUsers", this.userService.listUsers());

        return "users";
    }

    @RequestMapping("userdata/{id}")
    public String userData(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("user", this.userService.getUserById(id));

        return "userdata";
    }
}
```

index.jsp

[image: index.jsp]

click on users list (users.jsp)

[image: users.jsp]

Comment: Normally, HTTP 404 means that the resource is not found.It seems the Controller or the accessed resource is not found. Can you post your 404 URL? And can you also post your Controller?!

Comment: In the `index.jsp`, what happen if you use `<a href="/users" target="_blank">Users list</a>`?

Comment: added the controller code and pages.

Comment: After running app, try to call this url directly "localhost:8080/users.jsp" and check as it is running or same error

Comment: you are probably missing a @Controller on your controller, how should spring guess it's a controller?

Comment: I tried "http://localhost:8080/users.jsp" and "http://localhost:8080/web-inf/pages/users.jsp", same 404 error.

Comment: Yes, RC is right, I missed the @Controller field